# how to change specific text in a column but keep the rest

Tags: sql, navicat

I am using SQL in navicat. I would like to change the UID below to id and keep the rest of the text in each column. The numbers after the = are different in each record.

EXAMPLE:

3PYTW2X?UID=5493139 and I want it changed to 3PYTW2X?**id**=5493139

3PYTW2X?UID=2986225 and I want it changed to 3PYTW2X?**id**=2986225

I have about 200k records that need to be updated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a replace function:

```
REPLACE(FieldName,'UID','ID')
```